# How to arrange list of tuples into a specific order

Tags: scala

I have a list of tuple string, which looks like given below.

```
val pp:List[(String,Int,Int,Int)]=List(("G",7,6,1),("L",7,7,1),("S",6,10,3),("R",5,10,3),("I",8,6,2),('L",9,6,2),("S",10,7,4),("P",10,8,4))
```

The fourth element of tuple shows the order in which they have inserted example

> `("G",7,6,1)` => here the fourth element i.e 1 of tuple shows that it was inserted first.

> `("R",5,10,3)` => here the fourth element i.e 3 of tuple shows that it was inserted 3rd

> `("P",10,8,4)` => here the fourth element i.e 4 of tuple shows that it was inserted fourth.

now, I want this to arrange in a order they have inserted, and also the tuple which was inserted at first will be in one array. example

> `("G",7,6,1),("L",7,7,1)` => this two inserted first so, output should
> be  `[["G,7,6,1" ,"L,7,7,1"]]`

> likewise other => `[["G,7,6,1" ,"L,7,7,1"],["I,8,6,2","L,9,6,2"],["S,6,10,3","R,5,10,3"],["S,10,7,4","P,10,8,4"]]`

I have already tried, groupby and seq and sort. it worked only for 4th insert. the moment I insert the 5th tuple it gives me output in random place example

> this is one insert => [["G,7,6,1" ,"L,7,7,1"],["I,8,6,2","L,9,6,2"],["S,6,10,3","R,5,10,3"],["S,10,7,4","P,10,8,4"]]

> for example , i have inserted this ("p",7,6,5),("p",7,7,5), ("t",7,6,6),("t",7,7,6).then it gives me ,

> [["p,7,6,5","p,7,7,5"],["G,7,6,1" ,"L,7,7,1"],["t,7,6,6","t,7,7,6"],["I,8,6,2","L,9,6,2"],["S,6,10,3","R,5,10,3"],["S,10,7,4","P,10,8,4"]]

this is wrong, it should have come like this

> [["G,7,6,1" ,"L,7,7,1"],["I,8,6,2","L,9,6,2"],["S,6,10,3","R,5,10,3"], ["S,10,7,4","P,10,8,4"],["p,7,6,5","p,7,7,5"],["t,7,6,6","t,7,7,6"]]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want something like this:

```
pp
  .groupBy(_._4) // groups by "insert order"
  .toSeq
  .sortBy(_._1) // sorts by "insert order"
  .map(_._2) // Seq[List[(String, Int, Int, Int)]
```

If you want specifically arrays you can add `.toArray` in the `map` and after it (i.e. `.map(_._2.toArray).toArray`) .

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list using "sortBy".

```
val sortedlist = (pp.sortBy(_._4))
```

If you want a special ordering, you can also add that.

```
 val sortedOrderedList = (pp.sortBy(_._4))(Ordering[Int])
 // Ordering[Int].reverse gives you the reversed sort, so descending
 println("sorted " +sortedOrderedList)
```

Then I don't quite understand what you mean by those that were inserted at first.
Do you mean all that have the same number in the third element? You could map or group those together too. But it feels like that's actually a separate question.

**Edit** after looking at Guru Stron's answer. You could group it first and then do sorting if want them grouped together.

```
val grouped = pp.groupBy(_._4).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
println("grouped " +grouped) 
// grouped List(List((G,7,6,1), (L,7,7,1)), List((I,8,6,2), (L,9,6,2)), 
// List((S,6,10,3), (R,5,10,3)), List((S,10,7,4), (P,10,8,4)))
```